# Не могу добавить Java Class файл в локальном репозитории github(IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea, github

Не могу добавить Java Class файл в локальном репозитории github(IntelliJ IDEA). В обычном проекте такая возможность есть.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если что, то методом тыка нашёл как исправить проблему). После этого можно добавлять package и java class[image: введите сюда описание изображения]